# Best way to handle multi-languages in documentation app

Tags: localization, internationalization

We have a SaaS web application (multi-tenant) for creating online documentation (like a wiki). 
Right now we only support English. We want to support other languages. We have all the interface controls set up to work, but we just need to figure out how to handle the actual user content.

It seems we are thinking about storing each page for each language separately. 
So if they user create a page "how to reset password", and wants it in English, Dutch, and Spanish, we would store 3 different version of that page in the database.

I would love any advice on this!!

Answer (score 0):

Using my own experience as examples - you have two choices really:

**Each language is completely seperate**

When a user wants to translate the contents of their documentation - they simply start a new, separate, complete version of the docs - and translate each page as they go. You could copy the existing docs as a start point but each language would in any case be independent. For example, this is how [the docs for CakePHP are currently organized](https://github.com/cakephp/docs). Each language is effectively independent which  allows the most flexibility. By flexibility I mean, for example, a page in one language doesn't *have to* exist in all the others - or with the same url/name.

The disadvantage here is keeping the versions in sync, or knowing when a translation needs updating (new changes to master language version).

**Store translations as versions of the original**

Alternatively you could store translations as versions of the master/main language. [that](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/879/Beginning-With-CakePHP) [is](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/es/view/879/Comenzando-con-CakePHP) [how](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/de/view/879/Der-Anfang-mit-CakePHP) [we](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/it/view/879/Iniziare-con-CakePHP) did it before. It made it easier to track what was being translated but at the cost of flexibility.

The disadvantage here is it's potentially too rigid - it may not be easy to add a page that is language specific, adding a new page in not-main-language could also cause problems

This is analogous to "`we would store 3 different version of that page in the database`".

Both of the mentioned approaches are quite valid, pick the one that solves the most problems whist giving the least issues :)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to deal with documentation in multilanguage applications is to avoid it by **embedding the documentation in your application, but not as entire pages, just as sentences.**.

Try to make the usage of your application as simple and intuitive as possible, include hints in the UI and for those who need more provide a forum split by languages.

Now, be sure that you have at least one person for each language that will report back any issues in the interface, so you could improve the texts or the design based on the input from them.

Comment: Thanks, but we have a web-app for creating online help documentation. The question was in regards to how we should allow our customers to create pages in different languages.

Comment: please provide a link so I can fully understand the issue.